# Spring boot - Why does my Restcontroller not release reference to a new POJO?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, garbage-collection

I have a spring rest controller that instantiates a new POJO. This POJO will be used to deserialise an XML object from a DB.

I've noticed with IDEAs Memory View plugin, that for the lifetime of my application, only one controller object is created (as expected) but for every request to the controller a new POJO instance is created and not garbage collected even after the request is complete.

This is resulting in out of memory exceptions.

What would be the best way to solve this?

```
@RestController
public class VendorController {

  private ChuckNorris chuckNorris;

  @RequestMapping("/vendor")
  public String vendors() {
    ChuckNorris chuckNorris = new ChuckNorris();
    chuckNorris.setType("roundhouse");

    return "test";
  }
}
```

In this code, every request creates a new ChuckNorris object and they hang around in memory until the application terminates.

Answer (score 0):

The created objects are not necessary to be freed just after exit of the method. They are freed on gc() call. Gc call depends on multiple params like timing, memory available etc. You can try to gc manually and check whether the objects still exist.

But normally it is not correct to have a reference to any object from Controller.

Why do you need this?

```
private ChuckNorris chuckNorris;
```

if controller has a reference to a POJO the POJO can't be destroyed. Try to remove the reference and rewrite your code to avoid storing the instances on Controller's level.

Can't tell you how exactly the code could be rewritten without understanding your business logic.

Comment: In my real world example the controller calls an Autowired service component. It actually creates the POJO and calls another Autowired service to populate it.
However when I complete the full http request/response and then perform another http request, the first POJO still remains in memory. 
It's like the service component creates a new POJO for every request but never releases its reference to it.